# Add <span> tag inside a string

Tags: c#-4.0, html

I want to wrap certain portion of the text in `<span></span>` tag

for example : I wan to put `"DataForStatsMCList.FirstOrDefault().Range1D1"` in `<span></span>` tag after the data being applied to it.

```
  mc_summary.Headers = new List<string>() { "Inventory Analysis",
                       "Prior 7 - 12 Months" + Environment.NewLine + "(" + 
                        DataForStatsMCList.FirstOrDefault().Range1D1 + ")"  };
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want the retrieved data to appear within the `<span>` tags? Or you literally want to write the code into a `<span>`?

Comment: I want code appear with in <span> tag.

Comment: What happens when you put `DataForStatsMCList.FirstOrDefault().Range1D1` within quotes and try write it as a string?